# SharePoint 2013 File Shredding and RBS

Tags: 2013, rbs

I am looking for insight into how to change the File Shredding settings in SharePoint 2013.  We leverage RBS for BLOB Offloading and want to increase the sizes of the chunks so they are more efficiently offloaded with RBS.

What we have found is this: 
* Editable Files/Chunks (Office Document and apparently MP4s): default chunk size is 64k. 
* Non-editable Files/Chunks (Zip Files, EXEs, and also WMVs): default chunk size is 1MB

When we change the "FileWriteChunkSize" with PowerShell it only adjusts the "Editable Files" default chunk size and the non-editable stay at 1MB.

Does anyone know why this is or how we would increase both Editable and Non-editable settings?

Answer (score 0):

I am still researching how this works myself, however:
The "shredding" term refers specifically to the methodology for storing the portion of the BLOB which has changed - therefore, it would not make sense for un-editable files to change.

Since we are investigating utilizing this functionality at my company, I'm curious if someone else has encountered this?